# Click on a submenu item in windows

Tags: windows, menu, click

all.

I'm trying to do the following, using standard windows menus. I have a menu with a sub menu attached to it. I need to perform different actions when user clicks the menu item that opens a submenu, and user hovers over the menu item and submenu opens without a click.

As far as I could see WM_MENUCOMMAND is only sent when user clicks on a menu item that does not have a submenu attached. Also no mouse click messages are sent when I actually click an item that contains submenu.

So is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can tell when the mouse moves over an item by watching for [WM_MENUSELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You would then have to start a timer, and if the timer expires before the cursor moves again, you'd have to manually pop open the submenu.  I'm not sure how to accomplish the second part.

And it's pretty non-standard behavior that might confuse users.  What are you trying to accomplish?  And how do you expect it to work for users with only keyboard access?

Comment: I'm not going to change the standard delayed sub menu opening behavior, I just need a different action when user actually clicks the item that contains submenu. I've seen this behavior in Microsoft Office 2010.

That's actually what users are asking for, we've tried to explain them this would be confusing, but they keep insisting.